# How to get coverage from React Create App frontend and NodeJs backend by running java Selenium tests?

Tags: reactjs, selenium-webdriver, create-react-app, createjs, istanbul

My Application is created from React Create App and and NodeJs backend. I am supposed to fetch the coverage for the same using the source code. I have the source code and Java Selenium scripts, but I am not sure how I can get the coverage for the same.

Istanbul is not able to Instrument React Create App frontend source code and It is mandatory to use Java Selenium scripts.

I was able to get the coverage using Cypress tests for the same.
Could anyone help?

Istanbul is not able to Instrument React Create App frontend source code and It is mandatory to use Java Selenium scripts.

I was able to get the coverage using Cypress tests for the same.
Could anyone help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.